# Command "npm run dev" fail

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

When I execute `npm run dev`, I am getting following error. I have also included my package.json file and config file.

> C:\Users\aksha\Desktop\forkify>npm run dev
>
> npm ERR! missing script: dev
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\aksha\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-12-07T18_22_36_160Z-debug.log

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');


module.exports = {
    entry: './src/js/index.js',
    output:{
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/js'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    mode: 'development'

};
```

package.json file

```
{
  "name": "forkify",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "forkify project",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack"
  },
  "author": "Aditi Aella",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "live-server": "^1.2.1",
    "webpack": "^4.41.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.1.5",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.9.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: "scripts": {
    "dev": "node index.js"
  }

Comment: still wont work

Comment: where is the path of your index.js?
maybe dev: node /src/js/index.js